# Apache PDFBox - merge documents without loading objects to memory

Tags: java, apache, pdf, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I'm trying to merge PDF documents using [PDFMergerUtility](https://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFMergerUtility.html). I was thinking about mergeDocuments() method but when i looked into the source code, the files are loaded as [PDDocuments](https://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html), which I'm trying to avoid, because my application works with huge images that are exported to pdf and creating PDDocument containing these images causes `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

Is there any way to merge these documents without loading the whole objects to memory, using PDFBox or similar tool?

Comment: *the files are loaded as PDDocuments, which I'm trying to avoid* - in that case PDFBox is not a library for you: For essentially every operation on a PDF, PDFBox requires it to be loaded into memory as `PDDocument`.

Comment: In the 1.8 version, you could try mergeDocumentsNonSeq with a scratchFile parameter. It will use less memory.